# Process HTML checkboxes and their values

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

How can I process the checkboxes only if they're checked and grab the value of the checked ones only.

**php**

```
if (is_array($_POST['add'])) {
  foreach ($_POST['add'] as $key => $value) {
    $_POST['add'][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($value));
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="wmeet_ce" 
        value="ce" 
        name="add[wmeet]" 
        title="Wanting To Meet" 
        class="checkbox {validate:{required:true,minlength:1}}"/>

<input type="checkbox" id="wmeet_sf"
        value="sf" 
        name="add[wmeet]" 
        class="checkbox"/>

<input type="checkbox" id="wmeet_sm" 
        value="sm" 
        name="add[wmeet]" 
        class="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only checked checkboxes are ever presented to PHP, so your PHP code is correct.

However, your HTML isn't correct, as all your checkboxes have the same name.  This means PHP will only ever see one of them.

To get an array of checkboxes you either need to give your checkboxes unique names like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="wmeet_ce" 
        value="ce" 
        name="add[ce]" 
        title="Wanting To Meet" 
        class="checkbox {validate:{required:true,minlength:1}}"/>

<input type="checkbox" id="wmeet_sf"
        value="sf" 
        name="add[sf]" 
        class="checkbox"/>

<input type="checkbox" id="wmeet_sm" 
        value="sm" 
        name="add[sm]" 
        class="checkbox" />
```

Or use the empty box technique like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="wmeet_ce" 
        value="ce" 
        name="add[]" 
        title="Wanting To Meet" 
        class="checkbox {validate:{required:true,minlength:1}}"/>

<input type="checkbox" id="wmeet_sf"
        value="sf" 
        name="add[]" 
        class="checkbox"/>

<input type="checkbox" id="wmeet_sm" 
        value="sm" 
        name="add[]" 
        class="checkbox" />
```

Comment: what happens when I use the empty technique, will it then retrieve the values of the checkbox i.e. ce, sf and sm?

Comment: You'll get an indexed array with the values of the checked ones in.  If you use the other technique you'll get an associative array.